# How can i implement java Rest with out Jersy

Tags: java, jsp, rest, jetty

Hello i am trying to develop a rest api .it have no need for performance issue or such complex design just two api . how can i develop it with out jersy using jetty server ??

Isn't there any way we can make a RESTful web service without using jersey or for that matter any other light weight libs ?

is there any Reasons for not directly write Servlets for creating a REST API ??

Comment: You could write raw servlet and do all the request processing yourself, but, that would require more time and effort to do right than to just use some existing framework (spring mvc, jersey, ...).

Comment: Sure. Use a servlet. But why would you *avoid* using Jersey? It exists to make it *simpler* to write a restful web service.

Comment: @MarkoŽivanović can u give some examples

Comment: @JBNizet not like that .. i like jersy, i made some complex applications using that it helps me a lot and makes simple ... i want to know how it works and requirement is so simple

Comment: Well, it examines the path, query string and headers of the request to choose which resource method to call based on their annotations, umarshalls to XML or JSON payloads to objects, calls the method, then marshalls the returned value to XML or JSON, and sends it with the appropriate headers and status, basically. All that is doable manually from the servlet API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for skeleton servlet. If you have issues making it run, let me know and I'll post complete sample project.

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        String query = request.getQueryString();
        writer.print("Hello. You said: " + query);
    }

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(req, res);
    }

}
```

Comment: is there any Reasons for not directly write Servlets for creating a REST API ??

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, the sample above IS the servlet. You can use it to directly parse request (query, headers, ...) and generate your response (plain text, html, json, xml, whatever else you want/need).

Answer (score 0):

REST is basically a concept over applied the HTTP protocol. You can implement it with Servlets and JSP, even thought it will be much harder to understand in a more complex scenario, when a base resource invokes sub-resource, building a chain call.

I would recommend that you stick to the JAX-RS specification for java REST services. It is very lightweight and easy to understand.